# GAS AddOn for Sheet : the script can't use Drive Service DriveApp

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, google-drive-api, add-on

I made a script that get a Drive folder by ID and then processes a function. I first used this script on the Apps Script Editor linked to a Google Sheet file on my Drive, before migrate to an Addon : it worked like a charm. This is what the code looks like :

Line 93 :

```
var parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('##folderId##');
```

Then, I published a private AddOn of that script for our domain on the Google Workspace MarketPlace. The function "DriveApp" won't work and the only log i received is :

> Uncaught  at functionName (Code:93)

I specify that my AddOn is published domain-wide and installed by administrator... The Google Docs says (here : https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive):

> However, if an add-on using the Drive service is published for
> domain-wide installation and is installed by the administrator for
> some or all users in the domain, or any Apps Script that has its OAuth
> client allowlisted by the domain administrator, the add-on functions
> for those users even if the Drive SDK is disabled in the domain.

I prefer using DriveApp than the Advance Drive API Service. Maybe a problem with "Google Workspace Add-ons" OAuth or ...? I am stucked.

Comment: I tried to add 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive' as oauthScopes in the manifest without success...

Comment: Enable the Drive API in the Google Cloud Project linked to your Google Apps Script project.

Comment: Thank you very much @Rubén, it works : I added the Drive API for the GCP Project. Also, "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive" needs to be written in the manifest.